# For SR timing diagrams, does a bubble on the output of Q' indicate that it is the same as Q?

Tags: flipflop, sequential-logic

[image]

I understand that with flip flops when there is a bubble on the clock it means the clock cycle is in terms of the falling edge, but when there is a bubble on the output Q' isn't this inverting Q twice, bringing it back to just Q? As in, "not Q' = Q"? I don't understand why this would be beneficial because now won't both output timing diagrams be the exact same?

Comment: The bubble, the \$^\prime\$ or the \$\circ\$ on the pin indicates inversion.  \$Q'\$ can also be indicated as \$\overline Q\$. \$Q'\$ is just the name of the pin with the bubble.

Comment: So whether it has a bubble or not at Q', it just means that Q' will be Q inverted?

Comment: Having a bubble and stating that the output is nQ is a tautology. I'd prefer to see just nQ with no added bubble.

Comment: You need the bubble as well if both \$Q\$ and \$Q'\$ are shown.  With microprocessors and other complex ICs only \$\overline X\$ is shown.

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't realize that when the bubble is there it still just means Q inverted. I thought it was doubling up or something. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A bubble on an input or output means 'inverted'.

That is why an inverter is shown as a buffer symbol (no logic state change) with a bubble on its output (then inverted).

The '>' on an input means that is it positive-edge triggered. It will react only to a LOW-to-HIGH transition.

An input with a bubble followed by '>' is negative-edge triggered. The logic gate inverts the input then looks for a positive edge transition. Therefore the gate input will react only to a HIGH-to-LOW transition.

To your example...

You have a negative-edge triggered SR flip-flop with complementary outputs. Your Q output will obey the Set/Reset (SR) function of the gate.

Your Q' output will always be driven with the inverse of the Q output. Its name is has an apostrophe to denote that it isn't Q. The symbol shows that it is inverted. The name and symbol are indicating the single inversion in different places.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! So even with a bubble at Q', it still represents just Q' (being the inverse of Q output)? It doesn't 'invert' twice? Essentially, why not just have Q' instead of bubble Q' if they are the same?

Comment: @lcmting17, because the symbol conforms to the convention for inversion. Q' is its name. It can't be called Q, can it - there's already a Q. The name Q' may be used or referenced in text (datasheets, specifications etc.) while the symbol is used on schematics. Don't burn yourself up on this, it's worked well for 54 years :-)

Answer (score 0):

Note that many EDA tools have gotten away from using the "bubble" to denote an active low input or output on a schematic symbol, and have gone with an ANSI/IEEE standard that uses a skewed triangle.  Here is an example of LVDS differential driver and receiver symbols:

[image: LVDS Driver Schematic Symbol]

[image: LVDS Receiver Schematic Symbol]

Comment: Yes, some EDA tools offer IEEE symbols as an option, but in my experience few designers use that style. IEEE symbology is kind of a dumpster fire really, starting with the 'arrow' indicating active low and you show in your example. To the unfamiliar it looks like a clock pin, or a directional. On the other hand the traditional 'bubble' notation used in ANSI symbols is kind of mnemonic: the "o" of the bubble looks like a "0" (zero).

Comment: Well for good or bad, the fact of the matter is many companies/industries have adopted the ANSII/IEEE standard symbols.  Our company has a couple of component librarians. One of their jobs is to create ANSII compliant schematic symbols.

Comment: I agree that the bubble is more intuitive.  But maybe that's because it predated the ANSII standards, and I saw that long before the ANSII standard came about.

Answer (score 0):

The 'bubble' is the symbol.

The *Q'* is the pin designation.

*Q'* is the inverse of *Q*.

Comment: Well in all fairness, the way OP posted his graphic it looks like Q and Q' are net names and not pin names.